# What is the result of a = (b==c)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a Computer Vision project in c++ and the OpenCv library. I often see that kind of code during my researches :
image_ is a cv::Mat 
c is a int

```
cv::Mat cluster = (image_ == c)*255;
```

I think it put a boolean value in cluster but I'm not really sure.

Comment: What are the types of `image_` and `c` in this example code?

Comment: You need to consult the OpenCV **documentation** about how it defines `==` (on the types of `image_` and `c`) and how it defines `*` (on the result of `==`, and `int`). Presumably `==` produces a matrix of 0/1 values, and presumably `*` produces that matrix scaled by the given number. But it could be that `==` produces a single `bool` value. Check the docs.

Comment: Update: after checking the docs, it's not matrix of 0/1 values but matrix of 0/255 values.

Comment: image_ is a cv::Mat and c is a int

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 6):

From the [OpenCV documentation of `==`](http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions) applied to its matrices:

> **”** The result of comparison is an 8-bit single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

and

> **”** Scaling: `A*alpha`

I.e. the so far three answers here that assume that `==` always produces a `bool` in this context, are wrong: it depends on the types of your `image_` and `c`, and if they're matrices the above quotes apply. If they're not, I'm not sure if the code will even compile. But you can check that.

Comment: in short: The result of `(image_ == c)` is a Matrix with entries 0 where image_ is not equal to c and 255 where image_ is equal to c. Each matrix entry is then multiplied by 255 which doesn't change anything because the 8 bit matrix is saturated to 255 :)
At least if the matrix type is a standard type.

Comment: and `image_` here is probably a `cv::Mat` (single channel), while `c` can be either a scalar, or a `cv::Mat` (single channel) with same size as `image_`

Comment: Thank you all for your help